# update rows in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I have three table:

```
user (id,name,password,......)

words (id,word,meaning)

userword (id, user_id,word_id,checking,old)
```

and i have a query in php :

```
$user= $_SESSION['userid'];
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *
                    FROM words
                    WHERE id
                    IN (
                            SELECT word_id
                            FROM userword
                            WHERE old =0
                            AND user_id =$user
                            LIMIT 10
                      ) 
                    ");
```

this query works properly but after this I want to update words that I selected and set old=1 for them
what can I do?

Comment: run an [update query](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Update_%28SQL%29)?

Comment: Er, see JOIN... and why are you limiting the result to 10 rows (and 10 'random' rows at that)!?!?

Answer (score 2):

I don't recommend using **mysql_* functions** because it's depreceated.

```
mysql_query("UPDATE userword SET old='1' WHERE old='0' AND user_id='$user' AND word_id IN(SELECT id FROM words) LIMIT 10");
```

A PDO approach would be :

```
$sql=$dbh->prepare("UPDATE userword SET old='1' WHERE old='0' AND user_id=? AND word_id IN(SELECT id FROM words) LIMIT 10");
$sql->execute(array($user));
```

More About **PDO** : [www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php)

Comment: I have a lot of words in userword that old=0 and user_id= $user for them but I want to update some of them that I selected them before